# What Does It Mean If findViewById finds view but setText or setImageResource Do not work

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

This problem is really driving me mad. I have spent 2-3 days just trying to pass it. I have a listview, I iterate through each list element to set their images from a drawable. I checked if findViewById works, and it does because logcat gave me the id it had. When I try to setImageResource or use Picasso to load the image from the internet nothing happens and the images do not appear.

Here is the ImageView definition in the XML:

```
 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/Photo"   
 android:layout_height="100dp"
 android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
  />
```

And here is the iteration process:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {


                   v = mAdapter.getView(i,null, list);

                  ImageView photo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Photo);

                   photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo);
               }
```

It looks a very simple task to do but for some reason it is not working. I tried cleaning the project if that might matter. Also, This is all in a fragment, and I have already used setAdapter on the list.

I really appreciate any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapter `getView()` gives you a new view. It's not the same that is displayed on screen and changing it doesn't have any visible results.

Move the `setImageResource()` code to the adapter `getView()` itself so it operates on the same views as requested by your list view.

Comment: If you need further help, consider posting your adapter `getView()` code to the question.

Comment: I am using a simplecursoradapter and I have not overridden the getView function. Can you please tell me how to do that? Should I create a new adapter that extends SimpleCursorAdapter and override that function? And If I do, how would that look like?

Comment: With cursor adapters, override `bindView()` instead and set your images there.

Comment: How can I override bindView() , do I need to write a custom adapter class? Excuse my ignorance but I am new to android development.

Comment: I created a custom adapter and have overridden the getView function and it's working. The images take time to load though.